# To remove zero when dragging a formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

please let me know if there any way to remove zero entries while dragging a formula. please take a look to this sheet i shared here.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sr4zf9h2HyC7jJTIO05735VogNWmlt-s287IAoIcCuQ/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a simple `IF` function

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(D4:D16="",,D4:D16-E4:E16))
```

[image]

The formula says:
If cells `D4:D16` are empty, return nothing. If not, return `D4:D16-E4:E16`.

Remember that since you are using the `ArrayFormula` function you do not need to drag the formula down. It will auto fill all cells within the range `F4:F16`.
If you need both column `D` and column `E` to be empty for returning empty cells, use the following formula.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(D4:D16*E4:E16=0,"",D4:D16-E4:E16))
```

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)

Comment: if u don't mind can u please help me to solve my previous question